# bad size image responsive when gatsby site is deploy on Netlify

Tags: deployment, graphql, gatsby, netlify, responsive-images

I make a Gatsby site with image fluid to have a responsive image on my site, that work fine in local development and when I build and use serve to deploy locally, all the images have a good size. But when it's deployed on Netlify the image choice is not the good one, and the result is little blur. The size choice to be display is just under the good one. I cannot figure what can I do to fix it...
I try to way to deploy : First by hosting my site on github, and the other by drag-and-drop my site on netlify.
So I'm little lost...

https://github.com/dinhostan/lavoieducode/blob/master/src/pages/stan/culture/artistes.js

https://lavoieducode.netlify.app/stan/culture/artistes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest removing the `maxHeight` attribute in the query ([line 62](https://github.com/dinhostan/lavoieducode/blob/master/src/pages/stan/culture/artistes.js#L62)) that's fixing the height intrinsically, constraining the image. You are setting a maximum height of `300px` in a container that is far bigger (`100vw` or `100%` of the viewport), creating an output like:

```
<picture><source srcset="/static/71cab95f897e5df896f6b7f6f158ce76/240b5/casey_reas_0.jpg 75w,
/static/71cab95f897e5df896f6b7f6f158ce76/ba5d5/casey_reas_0.jpg 150w,
/static/71cab95f897e5df896f6b7f6f158ce76/99d74/casey_reas_0.jpg 300w,
/static/71cab95f897e5df896f6b7f6f158ce76/1e170/casey_reas_0.jpg 450w,
/static/71cab95f897e5df896f6b7f6f158ce76/0d31e/casey_reas_0.jpg 600w,
/static/71cab95f897e5df896f6b7f6f158ce76/ad7ed/casey_reas_0.jpg 914w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"><img sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" srcset="/static/71cab95f897e5df896f6b7f6f158ce76/240b5/casey_reas_0.jpg 75w,
/static/71cab95f897e5df896f6b7f6f158ce76/ba5d5/casey_reas_0.jpg 150w,
/static/71cab95f897e5df896f6b7f6f158ce76/99d74/casey_reas_0.jpg 300w,
/static/71cab95f897e5df896f6b7f6f158ce76/1e170/casey_reas_0.jpg 450w,
/static/71cab95f897e5df896f6b7f6f158ce76/0d31e/casey_reas_0.jpg 600w,
/static/71cab95f897e5df896f6b7f6f158ce76/ad7ed/casey_reas_0.jpg 914w" src="/static/71cab95f897e5df896f6b7f6f158ce76/99d74/casey_reas_0.jpg" alt="" loading="lazy" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover; object-position: center center; opacity: 1; transition: opacity 500ms ease 0s;"></picture>
```

Note the `sizes="(max-width: 300px)"` among the `picture` tag.

I find it strange that this approach works locally but, if you want to give it a try, you can [force the Node version to the Netlify side creating a `.nvmrc`](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/manage-dependencies/#node-js-and-javascript) file in the root of your project with your local Node version. This will ensure that both environments (local and Netlify) work under the same Node umbrella. Just run:

```
node -v > .nvmrc
```

As I said, this will create a `.nvmrc` file in the root of your project that Netlify will catch during the deployment to set the Node version (key when installing dependencies).

Comment: You have solved the problem as usual! You're a real gatsby-react magician... Thx for the trick to force my app work like in real deployment.